# Об авторском оформлении прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь, авторская-пунктуация

Почему прямая речь стала оформляться **не по классическим правилам**? Может быть, это верно, и нужно просто внести изменения в правила? Но как это пропускают в издательствах, или там особый подход к авторам?

*Антонина Павловна, помолчав, приложила палец к губам. Тс-с, сказала она Глебу, понимаешь, ей нужен рядом надежный человек, только где его найдешь? А папа, спросил Глеб, – он ненадежный? Папа… Бабушка вздохнула и развела руками.* (Из современной прозы.)

Comment: "Нужно внести" не относится к "может быть"? Я о запятой.

Comment: Ах, Артем, что же вы давите на "художку" своим формализмом? :))  Я хочу сделать там паузу, неудобно читать такой длинный текст в одну фразу, да еще с вопросительной интонацией. Поэтому у меня –  "не относится" (авторский выбор).

Comment: Ну понятно, простите! Просто мой стиль не допускает там запятой, вот и решил уточнить. ;)

Comment: Артем, по правилам там не нужна запятая, так что вы правы, но я делаю ударение на "верно".

Comment: А я и на "верно", и на "нужно". Подразумевается, что *и поэтому нужно.*

Comment: **Тсс** I нескл. ср. разг. (В словаре РЯ Ефремовой и др). Здесь не по классике и *Тс-с*.

Comment: Вроде бы да. Вот вопрос № 260888  
Здравствуйте. Нигде на смогла найти. Тссс! или Т-с-с-!, Ммм... или М-м-м... ?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Корректно: Тсс! Мм...   Также: https://kartaslov.ru/как-правильно-пишется-слово/тсс

Answer (score 2):

Нацкорпус:

> Все вышло так неожиданно, сказала она, и так непонятно, и я
> получилась, какой бываешь, когда, раскинув руки, долго кружишься на
> месте и перекружишься, и земля выворачивается из-под ног, а ты с нее
> спадаешь и начинаешь как бы за землю хвататься, а на самом деле на нее
> падаешь (1994).

> Не говори, я прошу тебя, ты же меня не знаешь, может, я тебе не
> подхожу, сказала она (1995).

> Конечно, мне интересно, сказала она, мне все-все интересно, что имеет хоть какое-то отношение к тебе, а теперь, когда ты столько рассказал, мне кажется, я знаю все или почти все, знаю тебя, но мне важней… (2001)

Следует ли прописывать такое оформление в правилах? Мне думается, нет, потому что это литературный приём. Что касается издательств, то там прекрасно понимают, что это литературный приём, поэтому никто "грамматической акривией" не страдает.

Comment: В ваших примерах представлен один персонаж, а в моем - диалог между двумя лицами (целых четыре фразы),  причем никак не выделенный. Некоторые авторы хотя бы курсивом выделяют. А зачем тогда другие  мучаются и страдают из-за этой прямой речи, их-то издательства вряд ли пропустят с таким оформлением. Литературный прием? Возможно, а в чем его смысл – выразить какую-то слитность, непрерывность речи, которая дается как воспоминание?

Comment: @Sharon имено, выразить поток сознания, или единство событий, или показать, что полилог происходит внутри рассказа персонажа... Много причин. Диалог можно запихнуть в одно предложение, ощутите эффект: *Я подпирал спиной входную дверь и слушал, как свекровь переругивалась с Катюшей: одевайся быстрее, неа, сейчас в угол поставлю, не поставишь, ты неисправимая девочка, а вот и исп... испранив... исправииимая!* А теперь представьте, насколько менее 'включённо' в восприятие героя этот диплог звучал бы, будь он оформлен 'по классике' — с кавычками и дефисами.

Comment: А здесь https://esquire.ru/letters/73672-brisben-fragment-novogo-romana-evgeniya-vodolazkina/ не хотят понимать. Никаких следов приёма. Страшно подумать: правили автора?

Comment: @shampar в "Брисбене", насколько я помню, этот приём и не использовался. Он использовался в "Лавре", где все до одного диалоги оформлены не "по классике". // Не существует литературных обстоятельств, при которых какой-либо приём стал бы *обязательным*. *Обязательный приём* — это оксюморон, так как обязательным (в общем случае) является именно правило, а приём — зачастую от него отклонение.